# Entity Framework projection behaviour

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

First post on here and quite a simple one.

I've been looking into simplifying some complex queries in an application I'm developing and I'm scratching my head a bit on the below.

So say I have these two classes:

A domain entity "EmailRecipient" (used with EF code-first so expect a SQL table to be generated with the same column names).

```
public class EmailRecipient
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
    public string ExchangeName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    public virtual List<SentEmail> SentEmails { get; set; }
}
```

and a simple class for JSON serialisation called "EmailLite" defined as

```
public class EmailLite
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FriendlyName { get; set; }
}
```

In my specialised EF6(.1.3) DbContext, I have a DbSet called EmailRecipients.

So naturally executing this linq expression against EmailRecipients

```
EmailRecipients.Select(x => new EmailLite
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            EmailAddress = x.EmailAddress,
            FriendlyName = x.FriendlyName
        });
```

the generated SQL is

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[EmailAddress] AS [EmailAddress], 
    [Extent1].[FriendlyName] AS [FriendlyName]
    FROM [dbo].[EmailRecipients] AS [Extent1]
```

So why when I do:

```
Func<EmailRecipient, EmailLite> projectionFunction = x => new EmailLite
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            EmailAddress = x.EmailAddress,
            FriendlyName = x.FriendlyName
        };

EmailRecipients.Select(projectionFunction);
```

do I get the below (complete) SQL generated:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[FriendlyName] AS [FriendlyName], 
    [Extent1].[ExchangeName] AS [ExchangeName], 
    [Extent1].[Surname] AS [Surname], 
    [Extent1].[Forename] AS [Forename], 
    [Extent1].[EmailAddress] AS [EmailAddress], 
    [Extent1].[JobTitle] AS [JobTitle], 
    [Extent1].[SubscribedOn] AS [SubscribedOn]
    FROM [dbo].[EmailRecipients] AS [Extent1]
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Cheers,
Sat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`IQueryable<T>.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548743(v=vs.100).aspx) takes an `Expression<Func<T,TOut>>` as parameter, the function you're actually using is [`IEnumerable<T>.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) which takes a delegate. Because of this, you are telling EF that from that moment on, you are using `IEnumerable` rather than `IQueryable` and the rest of the query will be executed in memory => you're fetching all the columns.

```
EmailRecipients   <-- in memory from here on --> .Select(projectionFunction);
```

All you need to do is change `projectionFunction` into an expression and it will work:

```
Expression<Func<EmailRecipient, EmailLite>> projectionFunction = x => new EmailLite
{
    Id = x.Id,
    EmailAddress = x.EmailAddress,
    FriendlyName = x.FriendlyName
};
```

Comment: Thank you - It had to be simple: I needed to look juuuuust a little closer :) cheers again Alexander.